# Explanation about cascade xml file lbpcascade_frontalface.xml

Tags: opencv

I've been searching the Internet for 2 weeks, but I could not find the answer I need.

I'm learning about Local Binary Pattern in Face Detection and I want to build an app to detect face in image without using OpenCV classes, I mean I want to build my own class(es).

I see this xml file "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml" in openCV. I think this file is used to recognize face by Local Binary Pattern algorithm, so I want to use it to recognize face in image, but I don't understand about data nodes.

What do they mean? How to use them?
Especially data in **leafValues** and **internalNodes** tags

```
<stages>
<!-- stage 0 -->
<_>
  <maxWeakCount>3</maxWeakCount>
  <stageThreshold>-0.7520892024040222</stageThreshold>
  <weakClassifiers>
    <!-- tree 0 -->
    <_>
      <internalNodes>
        0 -1 46 -67130709 -21569 -1426120013 -1275125205 -21585
        -16385 587145899 -24005</internalNodes>
      <leafValues>
        -0.6543210148811340 0.8888888955116272</leafValues></_>
```

I'm sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: Two ways I would try: (1) Ask this question in opencv forums. (2) Dig into the code ....    Good luck and sorry for stating the obvious.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the 1st way. I tried the 2nd and failed!

Answer (score 1):

These nodes are the connecting dots of a facial layout. This xml exactly defines a front-face layout in terms of the dots ie:- there are dots defined for the pupil, right-cheek, left temple etc.

Comment: Pls check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840310/how-to-understand-face-detection-xml